# HTML5 fallback to flash player shows error before jwplayer starts

Tags: video, html5-video, jwplayer

HTML5 Video code emebed on a page

```
<video id="playerlkj32" width="640" height="300" controls="controls" preload="none"poster="video_thumb.jpg">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Shows error "MIME type not supported" before video plays with the jwplayer.

How do I eliminate the error message from popup?

I tried emebeding the object code inside video tag still gets the error

```
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf"
   width="854" height="504">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4">
    <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="player.swf"><![endif]-->
    <img src="video.jpg" width="854" height="480" alt="Video">
    <p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 video. <a href="video.webm">
     Download it</a> instead.</p>
</object>
```

Comment: Which browser you are using to test the app?

Comment: I need to remove the html5 video code and replace it with <div>

Comment: @Shamse I am having issue with firefox. it does not support mp4,mp4 or flv

Comment: If you're providing an MP4, make sure your server is putting a MIME type of "video/mp4" on the file. If it's not, that's a server configuration error. When it comes to FLV's, no browser can play an FLV without a Flash script of some sort (like JW Player). But you're using a very obsolete version of JW Player (looks like 5.x). JW Player 6 is not embedded with an <object> tag.

Comment: Where is your JW Player Set Up Code here?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I am using a Drupal Jwplayer module. I tried embeding Object into html5 video element as per this link https://dev.opera.com/articles/html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/. Still the error show before the jwplayer replaces with the Object Ebed

Comment: Which module? We don't have an official JW Player Drupal Module.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Here is the module https://www.drupal.org/project/jw_player.

Comment: Correction, we have a module for JW5, not for JW6. This module is not made by us.The author is 'rickvug ' - "Posted by rickvug on April 30, 2011 at 5:34pm "

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<video width="640" height="300" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```